# Find all automorphisms of the multiplicative group mod $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

The question is to determine all pairs of integers $(m, n)$ such that $f (a) = a^m$ maps a reduced system of residues modulo $n$ bijectively to itself. I have only found those trivial automorphisms given by $m\equiv1 \mod \phi(n)$, where $\phi$ is the Euler Totient Function. However, I'm not sure if there is any non-trivial automorphisms given by such $f$.

Any help and I would be grateful.

Comment: Inversion is always an automorphism, so $m \equiv -1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$ should also work. Have you tried any special cases of $n$, like $n = p$ a prime, or $n = p^k$ a prime power?

Comment: If $n=11$, Leo, doesn't $m=3$ work?

Comment: It works. Then I must have missed something.

Comment: Since this is a finite set, all injections are bijections. So when is $a\mapsto a^m$ not an injection?

Comment: The title does not reflect the question

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The image of $a \mapsto a^m$ coincides with the image of $a \mapsto a^d$ where $d=\gcd(m,\phi(n))$.