# Outer automorphism group of multiplicative group of integers modulo n

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, automorphism-group

What is $\text{Out}(G) = \text{Aut}(G) / \text{Inn}(G)$ when $G = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^\times$? For example, when $p$ is prime, which automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}^+$ arise as conjugation, and what happens when we quotient $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^\times) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}^\times$ by $\text{Inn}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^\times)$?

EDIT: $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^\times$ is abelian... I'm posting the question because I hope it will save time for other people in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing the question I found [A question about automorphism and inner automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177079/a-question-about-automorphism-and-inner-automorphism-of-mathbbz) and realized there is a very simple answer.

$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^\times$ is abelian since $\mathbb Z$ is abelian. And if $G$ is an abelian group, then $\text{Inn}(G) = \{ x \mapsto gxg^{-1} : g \in G \} = \{ x \mapsto x \}$, so $\text{Inn}(G)$ is trivial. Another way to see this is that $Z(G) = G$, so $\text{Inn}(G) \cong G / Z(G) = G/G \cong \{ 1 \}$. Thus $\text{Out}(G) = \text{Aut}(G)/\{\text{Id}_G\} \cong \text{Aut}(G)$.

So answering [Find all automorphisms of the multiplicative group mod $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3759771/find-all-automorphisms-of-the-multiplicative-group-mod-n) would answer the unnecessarily complicated question I asked.